# The filesystem 'P4ROOT' has only 1.9G free, but the server configuration requires at least 2G available

Tags: digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04, perforce

I'm working on a Perforce server hosted on Digital Ocean, Linux Ubuntu 18.04.3.

I've run out of file space on the server (according to the perforce configuration)

The trick is that I can't change the configuration as long as it's within this 2G threshold, the server continually rejects P4 Configure commands as well.

Digital Ocean can't downsize after you add more server space, and I feel like I might run into the same issue again so I'd prefer to learn how to actually fix it.
I'm an artist by trade, and while I can mostly follow documentation, specificity is required.

The P4 Config commands don't work, and return the same error. I can't check anything out, I can't obliterate any files to free up space.

Not sure what to do, my whole project is frozen.

Comment: The way to "actually" fix it is to add a lot more space to the server, permanently.  Disk usage tends to grow over time; if you obliterate a few files, compress the db, etc, but you don't actually allocate more disk space, it'll free up some space now, and then you'll be right back here in a few months if not a few weeks.

Comment: Curious: why can't you add more server space? I am not sure I understood that part

Comment: But the quick fix is to log in to the server and move crud out of there, because odds are good there's plenty of crud in P4ROOT that doesn't need to be in P4ROOT.  Rotate the log, checkpoint (to rotate the journal) and then move all the checkpoints and old journals you might have out of the server root and into backup storage (they shouldn't be in the server root in the first place).  Again: this is not a real fix, because you'll probably get just enough space from that cleanup to be just under the limit, which will allow you to obliterate some stuff, and then you'll hit it again soon enough.

Comment: Changng the configuration to let you get closer to the wire is a *really* bad solution because, again, you'll hit the limit soon enough anyway, and lowering the limit just makes it more likely that you'll actually overrun the available storage on the disk, which puts you in a situation that's harder to recover from.

Comment: @blurfus both because it's more expensive and because it's permanent, where I know I have a lot of files I don't need right now clogging the current system

Comment: @Samwise assuming I add more server space to get around this problem, how do I set it so I know I'm going to reach that limit and not hit it? 
If I knew a submit was going to do this I'd have deleted unnecessary version stuff beforehand

Comment: Set `filesys.depot.min` higher than `filesys.P4ROOT.min` (I'm assuming they're actually the same filesystem) -- I believe that'll block depot writes but not db writes.

Comment: Can you determine which files you do not need right now that are clogging the system? If so, why not get rid of them? - If not, you need a more permanent solution.  We all know that, as you keep track of history/versions of your code, your file system usage will grow - so a permanent solution is needed and actually desirable. Yes, it will be more expensive... that's how cloud providers work (not to mention that saving money is not really the primary focus of stackoverflow's Q&As)

Answer (score 2):

The *temporary* fix to lower the disk space thresholds is to use `p4d -c` to modify the appropriate `filesys.*.min` configurables:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4d -h
Usage:

    p4d [ options ]
    p4d [ options ] -j? [ -z | -Z ] [ args ... ]

    ...

    Configuration options:
        -cshow
        '-cset [server#]variable=value'
        '-cunset [server#]variable'

        This syntax provides a limited subset of the functionality of the
        'p4 configure' command, and is useful for accessing the configuration
        when the server is down. The '-cshow' flag displays the contents of
        the db.config table, similar to 'p4 configure show allservers'.
        The '-cset' and '-cunset' flags set or unset a configurable. When
        using set or unset, enclose the entire expression in quotation marks,
        and on Windows, use double quotation marks, not single ones.
```

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 help configurables

   Perforce server configurables

        ...

        filesys.depot.min     250M Minimum space for depot filesystem
        filesys.extendlowmark  32K Minimum filesize before preallocation(NT)
        filesys.P4ROOT.min    250M Minimum space for P4ROOT filesystem
        filesys.P4JOURNAL.min 250M Minimum space for P4JOURNAL filesystem
        filesys.P4LOG.min     250M Minimum space for P4LOG filesystem
        filesys.TEMP.min      250M Minimum space for TEMP filesystem
```

This will allow you to run commands like `p4 obliterate` etc that will free up a bit of space.  Once you're done, you should return the thresholds to their previous values, because it's pretty easy to blow through that buffer and *actually* run out of disk space (which is much more difficult to recover from than hitting a soft limit).

The long-term solution is to increase the amount of available disk space.  I've talked to many many Perforce admins who run out of disk space, say "no problem, I'll obliterate some stuff" (or compress the db via checkpoint restoration, or whatever else turns up on a "how to free up space in a Perforce server" google search), and they're inevitably back in the same position within a few months, except that they've already deleted/obliterated all the "easy" stuff and now have to start cutting closer to the bone, so now it takes a lot longer to figure out what they can afford to free up.  And then the next time it's even harder.  It's much easier (and in almost all cases *much* cheaper if you consider your own time to have any value at all) to just increase the amount of disk space and forget about it.